# bind load event to newly created jQuery object when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to just click a button create my object which is a form but when the button fires it loads the form. My constructor could all be wrong so if you find any faults or suggestions they would be appreciated. I've commented my code where Im having trouble

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.WikiForm = function (options) {
            this.Mode = options.mode || 'CancelOk' || 'Ok' || 'Wizard';
            current = jQuery('.wikiform .wizard :first');
            var width = 0;
            function positionForm() {
                jQuery('.wikiform .wizard .view').each(function () { width += jQuery(this).width() });
                jQuery('body')
                    .css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
                jQuery('<div id="overlay"></div>')
                    .insertBefore('.wikiform')
                    .css('top', jQuery(document).scrollTop())
                    .animate({ 'opacity': '0.8' }, 'slow');
                jQuery('.wikiform')
                    .css('height', jQuery('.wikiform .wizard .view:first').height() + jQuery('.wikiform .navigation').height() + 10)
                    .css('top', window.screen.availHeight / 2 - jQuery('.wikiform').height() / 2)
                    .css('width', jQuery('.wikiform .wizard .view:first').width() + 10)
                    .css('left', -jQuery('.wikiform').width())
                    .css('overflow', 'hidden')
                    .animate({ marginLeft: jQuery(document).width() / 2 + jQuery('.wikiform').width() / 2 }, 750);
                jQuery('.wikiform .wizard')
                    .css('width', width)
                    .css('height', jQuery('.wikiform .wizard .view:first').height());
            }
            if (this.Mode == "Wizard") {
                return this.each(function () {
                    /* <-- this function here not binding */                        
                    jQuery(this).bind('load', function (){                         
                        positionForm();
                    });
                    jQuery('.wikiform .navigation input[name^=Next]').click(function () {
                        if (current.next().length == 0) return;
                        jQuery('.wikiform .wizard').animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + current.width() + "px" }, 750, null, function () {
                            current = current.next();
                        });
                    });

                    jQuery('.wikiform .navigation input[name^=Back]').click(function () {
                        if (current.prev().length == 0) return;
                        jQuery('.wikiform .wizard').animate({ marginLeft: '+=' + current.prev().width() + 'px' }, 750, null, function () {
                            current = current.prev();
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else if (this.Mode == "CancelOk") {
                return this.each(function () {

                });
            } else {
                return this.each(function () {

                });
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*
        jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {

        });
        */
        jQuery('button[name=button1]').bind('click', function (e) {
            jQuery(".wikiform").WikiForm({ mode: 'Wizard', speed: 750, ease: "expoinout" }); 
            /* problem here initalizing the load */
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    body 
    {
        margin:0px;
    }
    #overlay 
    {
        background-color:Black; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%;
    }
    .wikiform 
    {            
        background-color:Green; position:absolute; display:block;
    }
    .wizard 
    {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .wizard .panel
    {

    }
    .view 
    {
        float:left;
    }
    .wizard .panel .view
    {
        float:left;
    }
    .navigation 
    {
        float:right; clear:left
    }
    #view1 
    {
        background-color:Aqua;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;

    }
    #view2
    {
        background-color:Fuchsia;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;           
    }
    #view3
    {
        background-color:Lime;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;           
    }
</style><form action="" method="">
<div id="layout">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height:2000px">
        <button id="button1" name="button1" value="1"> Click Me! </button>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
<div id="formView1" class="wikiform">

    <div class="wizard">

        <div id="view1" class="view">
            <div class="form">
                Content 1
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div id="view2" class="view">
            <div class="form">
                Content 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="view3" class="view">
            <div class="form">
                Content 3
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <input type="button" name="Back" value=" Back " />
        <input type="button" name="Next " class="Next" value=" Next " />
        <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: The `load` event can only be used with elements associated with a URL (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).  Since you're binding that event to a `<div>`, it's never going to be called.  What event are you trying to listen for?

Comment: I need some kind on initalisation when the button is clicked cos it's not firing. the whole thing just initialised when the onload event fired. so all I want it to do in position the form on the click event and have it animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just place the call to `positionForm()` at the end of the initialization code? Something like this:

```
if (this.Mode == "Wizard") {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery('.wikiform .navigation input[name^=Next]').click(function() {
            if (current.next().length == 0) return;
            jQuery('.wikiform .wizard').animate({
                marginLeft: '-=' + current.width() + "px"
            }, 750, null, function() {
                current = current.next();
            });
        });

        jQuery('.wikiform .navigation input[name^=Back]').click(function() {
            if (current.prev().length == 0) return;
            jQuery('.wikiform .wizard').animate({
                marginLeft: '+=' + current.prev().width() + 'px'
            }, 750, null, function() {
                current = current.prev();
            });
        });
        positionForm();
    });
}
```

I updated your code in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vztcq/

**Edit**: To center your modal dialog vertically, use `$(window).height()` instead of `window.screen.availHeight` when calculating the vertical position.  See jQuery's documentation for [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) for more info.  Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/bBCeq/

A few other things I noticed:

- You could be using `$` instead of `jQuery` inside of your plugin code.  The anonymous function that sets up the plugin takes a parameter called `$` and takes `jQuery` in as a parameter.  This will make your code a little more readable, in my opinion.
- When you're setting multiple CSS rules with jQuery, you can use an object that defines multiple properties: `$(..).css({'width': '10px', 'height': '10px'});` for example.
- Make sure your `<form>` has an ending `</form>`.  In the code you posted the closing tag was missing.
- Cache commonly used queries (e.g. `var $wikiForm = $(".wikiform")`)
- Use id selectors rather than class selectors whenever possible.

Comment: do you know how to position my form vertically centered